# Saga / Processmanager?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm thinking about this scenario:

I can receive customer inquiries by Email.

Those inquiries can be sent from existing customers or unknown "customers" - I'll call  latter "Leads".

When receiving an inquiry by Email from a Lead, a Sales Representative will need to register a new Lead in the Customer Relations Bounded Context (CRM BC) record the inquiry in the Sales Bounded Context (S BC).

I want to create a single task based UI so the Sales Representative doesn't have to use two UIs/Forms to accomplish the task.

I don't want the UI to issue two commands, so I came up with the consideration to have a `RecordLeadFromInquiryByEmailCommand` which then should cause the CRM BC to persist the Lead information. After this has finished, the Inquiry information should be persisted using a `RecordLeadInquiryFromEmailCommand` triggered by the `LeadFromInquiryByEmailCommandRecordedEvent` event from the CRM BC.

What's unclear for me right now:

- The inquiry data like "title" or "description" for the Inquiry needs to be passed with the `RecordLeadFromInquiryByEmailCommand` and the `LeadFromInquiryByEmailCommandRecordedEvent` event to be available for the `RecordLeadInquiryFromEmailCommand`. I'm wondering if the Claim Check Pattern would be right here or if this is too much overhead.
- Is this more of a saga or a process manager (I want to roll back if either command fails)?
- Does this even make sense?

Comment: So is there any need to reuse the second command on it's own?  Or can you just have a conditional path on your `RecordLeadInquiryByEmailCommand`?  Unless you are composing separate commands that would be used is multiple contexts, just keep the one command to process the email and conditionally create a lead.

Comment: I would like to be able to make a distinction between inquiries from leads and customers (which exist already) for example. I was thinking it might be more expressive and usable (thinking of asking which events happened instead of introspecting the payloads) to have different events instead of having properties with different payloads depending on lead vs. customer.

Comment: Commands generate the events.  And the events are part of the record.  I'm not asking to remove any event generated.  Just asking if there really was a need to separate the commands.

Comment: So you would emit two events from the command?

Comment: I would emit any number of events as is called for by processing the command.  That includes the optional second event.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - will do it that way.